# Sharing a URL within a tweet

Tags: php, twitter

I want a link to appear within a twitter tweet. At the moment the raw HTML comes out.

```
click <a href=\"www.google.com\">here</a> to test
```

Here is my code.

```
$url = 'www.google.com'
$text = urlencode( "click <a href=\"www.google.com\">here</a> to test" )

$share   = 'http://twitter.com/share';
$url     = '?url=' . $url;
$text    = '&text=' . $title;
$hashtag = '&hashtags=' . $hashtag;
$url     = $share . $url . $text . $hashtag;
```

Without `urlencode()` the actual twitter icon then spits out HTML text everywhere on my page.

Comment: ...in the first line @PedroLobito ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twitter auto converts url. but i dont think you can do anything more than what stated here because of anti spam policy. https://support.twitter.com/articles/78124